# Last time User Profile was used on list of workgroup computers

Tags: powershell, batch-file, search, directory

I need to search through a list of work group computers via the Users Profile Folder \computer\C$\users. I don't always know the full login name, or naming convention of the accounts, so need to invoke the use of wildcards e.g Simon Heffner may have a login folder (according to naming convention) of Heffensi, Simonhe or Heffnsi, that type of thing.

Using the last modified date of a certain file within the user folder I want to list computers he's possibly logged into at the time the script is ran, or at least within the last 2 weeks just in case they use / share more than one.

Research leads me to this file being a good identifier of logon activity.

```
"\\%%A\C$\Users\*%search%*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\UsrClass.dat"
```

I have some code that works but only so far and needs to be improved.

```
:start
CLS
echo.
echo ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
set /p search=Input search string:-

for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("%~dp0hostsfs.txt") do (

if exist "\\%%A\C$\Users\*%search%*" echo "%search% string was found in users folder on %%A" && powershell -Command "& Get-ChildItem "\\%%A\C$\Users\*%search%*\AppData\Local\temp"

)
pause & goto start
```

This works as intended, but does NOT use the file I refer to earlier (usrclass.dat) and if the user has logged on to multiple PC's (which is often)
the output from the power-shell command is overly verbose, in no order, and makes it quite difficult to find the recently used profiles. If I add the (usrclass.dat) file to the script, the power-shell command does nothing, it seems to be skipped.

What I would like some assistance with is:-

- List item

Making the power-shell work with the (usrclass.dat) file for more accurate last logged on reporting.

- Make the output easier on the eye to search multiple logon times to the PC

--Output example--

```
"test string was found in users folder on TEST-PC2"


    Directory: \\TEST-PC2\C$\Users\test\AppData\Local


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       09/11/2016     21:40                Temp

"test string was found in users folder on TEST-PC3"


    Directory: \\TEST-PC3\C$\Users\test\AppData\Local


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       09/11/2015     21:40                Temp

"test string was found in users folder on TEST-PC4"


    Directory: \\TEST-PC4\C$\Users\test\AppData\Local


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       09/11/2013     21:40                Temp
```

--Desired Output Example--

```
"test string was found in users folder on TEST-PC2"

User                                                  LastWriteTime
----                                                  -------------
test                                              11/11/2016 5:44:34 PM
test                                             1/15/2015 5:44:34 

"test string was found in users folder on TEST-PC3"

User                                                  LastWriteTime
----                                                  -------------
test                                             1/15/2015 5:44:34 

"test string was found in users folder on TEST-PC4"

User                                                  LastWriteTime
----                                                  -------------
test                                             1/15/2014 5:44:34
```

So from here I can easily see that test PC2 will be more than likely the PC he uses on the network, and then I can do tasks (load software silently etc.) to that PC and not the ones he clearly doesn't use.

```
   echo ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
set /p search=Input search string:-

for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("%~dp0hostsfs.txt") do (
For /d %%i in ("\\%%A\C$\Users\*%search%*") DO Psexec \\%%A -i net user %%i | find "Last logon"

)
```

### edit @16/11/2016 managed to suss it out, just in case some else needs this, I had to apply a multiplier to the %%i variable to expand just the folder name of the wildcard, which would always be the users log in, and then use that in the net use command in conjunction with psexec. Code Below.

```
:start
cls
echo.
echo :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
set /p search=Input search string:-

for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("%~dp0hosts.txt") do (
echo.
For /d %%i in ("\\%%A\C$\Users\*%search%*") DO echo %%~nxi found on %%A & Psexec \\%%A net user %%~nxi | find "Last logon"
)
pause & goto start
```

further edit this makes it a bit easier to read and separate multiple entries

```
:start
cls
echo.
echo :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
set /p search=Input search string:-
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("%~dp0hosts.txt") do (
echo.
For /d %%i in ("\\%%A\C$\Users\*%search%*") DO (
echo %%~nxi found on %%A & (
echo. 
%~dp0Psexec.exe \\%%A net user %%~nxi | find "Last logon")
    )
)
echo :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
pause & goto start
```

Comment: If you are in a domain environment you should consider updating your login scripts to create a log of what computer users are using. We created two at my last job. One log file was updated that was named computername.txt and the other username.txt. That way if I wanted to see what computers a person has used I could just find the log file named with their username and if I wanted to see who is logging into a specific computer, I could find the log named for that computer. Just something for you to think about.

Comment: Good idea.  Problem is I visit different places and the rooms where I need to install are often in use.  I making things easier for me installing software silently via psexec and the computer name hence the need for this.  I visit a different network daily as an engineer.

Comment: Not understanding why you are using Powershell to get that last bit of information.

Comment: It's what I found that worked

Comment: It's what I found that worked

Comment: Once you find a folder within the users folder that matches your search pattern then just use the net user command with that user name match to get the last logon date.  `net user squashman | find "Last logon"`

Comment: Don't use IF EXIST to find the folder that matches you search pattern. Just use a `FOR /D` command then you will have the folder name in a variable for you to use with the `NET USER` command.

Comment: Awesome,  thanks.  Will test and report back soon.

Comment: Edited original post to see it better,  having some issues getting syntax correct,  I think I have it but must be missing something as when I search the script breaks and closes

Comment: You will need to use psexec to run the net user command on the remote machine you are checking.

Comment: You are missing the DO in the second FOR command.

Comment: The %%i doesn't get turned into the username folder,  that's why,  did an echo and its just %i, what to do?

Comment: You should never just get %i as the output.  The do clause will never execute if the IN clause finds no matches.  Regardless of that you do not want to use the -i option with PSEXEC.  Read the help and you will see why.

Comment: Seems the wildcard thing doesn't get passed to PSexec,  tried normally perfect,  as soon as I try With wild card,  net user error,  have taken - i out too :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128070/discussion-between-tika9o9-and-squashman).

Comment: Please post your edit as an answer and accept it, if it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

final answer, formatted properly

```
:start
cls
echo.
echo :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
set /p search=Input search string:-
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("%~dp0pxhosts.txt") do (
echo.
For /d %%i in ("\\%%A\C$\Users\*%search%*") DO (
echo %%~nxi found on %%A & (
echo. 
%~dp0Psexec.exe \\%%A net user %%~nxi | find "Last logon")
    )
)
echo :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
pause & goto start
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method I've put together that produces very neat easy to read output is by querying the modified date of the user profiles usrclass.dat file (updates with every logon).

The previous answer using PSEXEC can be overly verbose and also reports error's all the time even though it finds the user the wildcard search. Hard to sift through with multiple entries found on several PC's.

fill pxhosts with list of hostnames & run. Just get nice list when ever its found of PC Username Last Modified Data (logon).

```
:start
cls
echo.
echo ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
set /p search=Input search string:-
echo.
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("%~dp0pxhosts.txt") do (
for /d %%i in ("\\%%A\C$\Users\*%search%*") DO (
for %%g in ("%%i\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\usrclass.dat") DO Echo [PC]'%%A' [User]'%%~nxi' [Last Login]'%%~tg'
    )
)
echo.
echo ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
pause & goto start
```

Example Output:-

```
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
Input search string:-adm

[PC]'DESKTOP-6285F8K' [User]'Admin' [Last Login]'09/11/2016 22:08'
[PC]'DESKTOP-6285F8K' [User]'Administrator' [Last Login]'25/10/2016 20:33'
[PC]'SRV-2008' [User]'admin' [Last Login]'21/11/2016 20:36'
[PC]'SRV-2008' [User]'Administrator' [Last Login]'21/11/2016 13:32'
[PC]'TEST-PC2' [User]'Admin' [Last Login]'21/11/2016 20:21'
[PC]'TEST-PC2' [User]'Administrator' [Last Login]'21/11/2016 20:48'

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
Press any key to continue . . .
```